# How to turn my single object into an iterable instance so I can merge it with another array?

Tags: javascript

I have a single object and an array of objects and now I'm trying to merge them using the spread operator like this:

```
let singleObject = { name: 'John', age: 20 }

let arrayOfObjects = [
    { name: 'Ben', age: 25 },
    { name: 'Casey', age: 30 }
]

let mergedArray = [...singleObject, ...arrayOfObjects];
```

However, this doesn't work since `singleObject` is just an object, whereas, `arrayOfObjects` is an array of objects.

So I'm wondering if I should use a different way to merge the object with the array or if I should just make the object iterable somehow?

Comment: You can simply push singleObject to arrayOfObjects.

Comment: let singleObject = { name: 'John', age: 20 };

let arrayOfObjects = [
    { name: 'Ben', age: 25 },
    { name: 'Casey', age: 30 }
];


arrayOfObjects.push(singleObject);

console.log(arrayOfObjects)

Comment: what do you mean by merging this object with the array? what's the expected output?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can change

```
let mergedArray = [...singleObject, ...arrayOfObjects];
```

to

```
let mergedArray = [{...singleObject}, ...arrayOfObjects];
```

Or

```
let mergedArray2 = Object.assign([], singleObject, ...arrayOfObjects);
```

```js
let singleObject = { name: 'John', age: 20 }

let arrayOfObjects = [
    { name: 'Ben', age: 25 },
    { name: 'Casey', age: 30 }
]

let mergedArray = [{...singleObject}, ...arrayOfObjects];

console.log(mergedArray)

let mergedArray2 = Object.assign([], [singleObject, ...arrayOfObjects]);

console.log(mergedArray2)
```

Comment: `Object.assign([], [singleObject, ...arrayOfObjects]);` that's just silly. You create `[singleObject].concat(arrayOfObjects)` plus a second, empty, array. And then you let `Object.assign()` copy value by value from one *(new)* array to the other?

Comment: @Thomas did you noticed `[singleObject, ...arrayOfObjects]` here `singleObject` is still reference, which i personally don't prefer reason for that is keeping things as pure as possible.

Comment: Yes, I did. Check `mergedArray2[0] === singleObject` in your code. So you wanted to use `Object.assign` to clone `singleObject`? then this version should look like `[Object.assign({}, singleObject), ...arrayOfObjects]`.

Answer (score 1):

You can just push yopur object into array like this, instead of concatinate

```js
let singleObject = { name: 'John', age: 20 }

let arrayOfObjects = [
    { name: 'Ben', age: 25 },
    { name: 'Casey', age: 30 }
]

arrayOfObjects.push(singleObject);

console.log(arrayOfObjects);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Array.of` as follows:

```js
let singleObject = { name: 'John', age: 20 }

let arrayOfObjects = [
    { name: 'Ben', age: 25 },
    { name: 'Casey', age: 30 }
]

let mergedArray = [...Array.of(singleObject), ...arrayOfObjects];
console.log(mergedArray);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```js
let singleObject = { name: 'John', age: 20 }

let arrayOfObjects = [
    { name: 'Ben', age: 25 },
    { name: 'Casey', age: 30 }
]

let mergedArray = [{...singleObject}, ...arrayOfObjects];
console.log(mergedArray);
```